# SVNX Lock issue

Tags: ios, svnx

First time I m facing this issue. When I try committing my project. I face issue like beloow

```
  svn: Working copy '/Users/administrator/Documents/Checkout/Mar 26 6.23 pm/XXX.xcodeproj' locked
    svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

My project is as noted as locked. What would be the issue? Tried in internet noting works out.
How can I remove locked state?

if I try clean SVN it shows error like

```
$svn cleanup
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/Users/administrator/Documents/Checkout/Mar 26 6.23 pm' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes when svn found the files inn working copy are not intended for committing to svn tool will lock such files and user have to release the lock before committing it.